# UITableview selection row button should deselected same position in another row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have list of 5 button in each row for `UITableViewCell` 
Total number of row count is 2.

If I select the first button in first row or second row then the other button of the same position should be deselect in another row vise versa

Please find the attachment:
[image]

Comment: Be more specific about your problem. Either post screenshot, sample code to describe your problem in detail.

Comment: show me some code how you are selecting first button.

Comment: put some code so i can give suitable solution.

Comment: You say that there are only two cells. So can a user select more than one buttons in one cell?

Comment: And are you using storyboard or nib?

Answer (score 0):

1 way:set relationships between your buttons and their owner cell. Reload layoutsubviews of cell to set its buttons' image.
2 way:set Tag for each button and reset corresponding button image in one button's action target.